# How to use OCI for XMLType columns in Oracle?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

In my application a new XMLType column was added to the database table. I have to read and write to that table using Oracle C API.
As I got from the web, the underlying data type of the XMLType is CLOB and as per my understanding the same API I used to manage CLOB columns should support XMLType columns as well.

My table is as follows (This table was not the actual one and using as POC).

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
    NIC NUMBER(10),
    MESSAGE XMLTYPE
);
```

SQL for select data

```
SELECT MESSAGE FROM STUDENT
```

However when fetching data it gave me the following error to the application.

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CLOB got OPAQUE TYPE
```

I defines the variable as follows.

```
pLocator = new OCILobLocator*;
*pLocator = NULL;

OCIDescriptorAlloc(p_DBCon->p_env, (dvoid **)pLocator, OCI_DTYPE_LOB, 
    (size_t)0, (dvoid **)0);

b_IsErr = OCIDefineByPos(p_sql, &p_dfn, p_DBCon->p_err, iPos, 
    (dvoid*)pLocator, -1, SQLT_CLOB, 0, 0, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

However I modified the SQL as follows and not it is working without any errors even for larger XMLs (More than 4k)

```
SELECT A.MESSAGE.GETCLOBVAL() FROM STUDENT A
```

So one part has been completed.

However, my second part which is for inserting data was failed.

My SQL is

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT (MESSAGE) VALUES (:1)
```

I do data binding as follows.

```
b_IsErr = OCIBindByPos(p_sql, &p_bnd, p_DBCon->p_err, iPos,
    (dvoid*)pzValue, iSize, SQLT_STR, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

In the execution it gives follows error.

```
ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

Please help me in getting this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This really is not easy task. Especially it's still questionable what are Oracle's intentions with the whole XML support. The API got changed between ver. 9i and 10i and now again there were some changes in 12c. But on the other hand in order to manipulate XMLTYPE as it was is "real" XML you need also a library called libxml.a (aside from usual libclntsh.so - oci.dll). This library is no more downloadable as part of "XDK toolkit", nether is missing in InstantClient, neither is not present in OracleXE. You realy need to install the "thick" Oracle client to get this library.

Then you have to bind XML column it as if it was a "complex" type. It really
is a complex type called `SYS.XMLTYPE` (this `SYS.` prefix is important).

So it should be:

```
b_IsErr = OCIBindByPos(p_sql, &p_bnd, p_DBCon->p_err, iPos,
(dvoid*)pzValue, iSize, SQLT_NTY, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

Once bound as SQLT_NTY, you have to manipulate it by using functions
from libxml.a library.

Best you should look at some complex OCI examples on Metalink or read source code of some open-source OCI wrapper library. For example [mine.](http://sourceforge.net/p/tora/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/tora/extlibs/trotl/src/trotl_xml.cpp).
But I have to admit that today there are better and actively maintained 
libs today.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which is far easier to use is to specify SQLT_CHR as the type. Then the server will automatically convert the XMLType to string and you can manipulate that string using whatever library you care to use. You do have to specify the maximum length of string you will accept -- or get into the more complex aspects of dynamic binding/fetching!